# Nav disappears when clicking on a button, this only needs to be at < 767

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, nav

My navigation disappears when clicking on a button, this needs to happen only when the viewport is < 767px. If the viewport is larger than 767px then the viewport doesn't need to be hidden.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $nav = $('#nav').
    prepend('<div class="responsive-nav" style="display:none">Navigation</div>').
    on('click', '.responsive-nav, ul a', function(evt) {
        if (evt.target.tagName === 'a' && $(window).innerWidth() >= 767) {
            return;
        }
        $nav.find('ul').slideToggle()
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){

        if ($(window).innerWidth() < 767) {
            $('nav ul li').css('display','block');
            $('nav ul').hide()
            $('.responsive-nav').show()
        } else {
            $('nav ul li').css('display','inline-block');
            $('nav ul').show()
            $('.responsive-nav').hide()
        }

    });

    $(window).resize();

});
```

I have made an example here for you to see what's happening:
https://jsfiddle.net/jcj0kph2/5/

Comment: what should be the behavior when the screen is wider than 767 and the user clicks on a menu item ?

Comment: I suggest defining a class in your CSS media query and setting that class on click. Then your JS won't need to be concerned with screen size.

Comment: @pparas , needs to be visible at all times (not toggle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`evt.target.tagName` returns the tag name in Caps.

> **[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName)**
>
> ....On HTML elements in DOM trees flagged as HTML documents, tagName returns the element name in the **uppercase** form.

So, here it returns `A`, change your `if()` to

```
if (evt.target.tagName === 'A' .....)
```

or

```
if(evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a'
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcj0kph2/6/)**

Comment: Ahhh, you found it. At some point I chainged it into a small "A" and didn't see any issues.. I feel stupid.

Comment: @Marc, happens :). I too had to debug on console and missed it at first.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like

```
if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a' && $(window).innerWidth() >= 767) {
    return;
}
```

in which case it will work for both cases.